# Object is possibly null in strict mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting *Object is possibly null* in typescript for the following event handler following and not for any other event handler function I coded

```js
<input
   type="file"
   className="hide"
   ref={hiddenInputRef}
   onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleInputOnChange(event)}
  />
```

```
 const [file, setFile] = useState<File>();
 const [fileName, setFileName] = useState<string>('');

 const handleInputOnChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    setFileName(event.target.files[0].name as string);
  };
```

The error goes away if I turn off strict mode in tsconfig.json file

[image]

Comment: Your problem is this access `files[0].name`: there's no guarantee that there's something at the zeroth spot in that array and you'd be trying to access `.name` of `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS is telling you that your ‘files’ array may have null values. There are two ways to handle: (1) address the null case, for example by writing code that says if files is null, do something else; (2) if you *know* files cannot be null you can tell TS that using the non null assertion operator ie files![0].